# Hyperledger, create a channel using the configtxgen CLI tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, config, blockchain, hyperledger, channel

I am following https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.1/create_channel/create_channel.html tutorial.
first of all, i didnt find TwoOrgsChannel in profile in configtx.yaml in my version, so i added this section to the profile and got it work and successes in creating a channel creation transaction for channel1.
but the command after that which will create the channel using peer channel create, return an error that i searched for but didnt get any similar post, which is:
Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- channel creation request not allowed because the orderer system channel is not defined

the section i had added to profile is:

```
TwoOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created Orderer profile in your configtx.yaml ?

Ordered system channel is required for order and peer for channel initialization.

Refer this link for configtx.yaml

https://medium.com/@msakhilvinayak/understanding-configurations-in-hyperledger-fabric-ff3f5c23625a